# What is PHP text editor plugin like Stackoverflow's? (WYSWYG)

Tags: plugins, wysiwyg, text-editor

I want to set my textarea in my php project with texteditor like Stackoverflow's. So I can input Text Code in special format display. Is there any plugin like that in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Creating text with some markup syntax is usally done on the client-side and not server-side, which is why I would recommend you look for a javascript-wysiwyg-editor.

Check out this [link](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/10-best-wysiwyg-text-and-html-editors-for-your-next-project/) for an overview.

Check out this [Blog Post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/reverse-engineering-the-wmd-editor/) for info on how [WMD Markdown Editor](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/) is used on Stack Exchange (as answered in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26412/what-wysiwyg-editor-is-stack-overflow-using) Meta question).